# Argument on why $\Bbb N$ does not have a least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

I am aware there is no least upper bound in $\Bbb N$. I am confused on the argument below, why this is true.

Suppose I have the set of natural numbers $\Bbb N$. Then I can pick a least upper bound imposed by $\Bbb R$ and name it $\alpha$.

Next I can say that I have an element $n\in\Bbb N : \alpha - 1 < n$. Then $\alpha < n + 1$, and so I have shown that $n + 1\in\Bbb N$. Thus there is truly no least upper bound.

Here is the exercise. I cannot wrap my head around the simple fact that $\alpha - 1 < n$. Shouldn't it be that $\alpha - 1 = n$? Then, $\alpha = n + 1$ and there is truly a least upper bound $n + 1 = \alpha$.

That is what is unclear to me: why $\alpha - 1 < n$. Shouldn't it be $\alpha - 1 = n$?

Comment: When you speak of an "upper bound in $\mathbb N$", the preposition "in" is confusing. Do you mean to consider potential upper bounds that are members of $\mathbb N$, or members of a larger set like $\mathbb R$? Once you decide what you're talking about, the rest will become clearer!

Comment: What I mean to say is upper bounds imposed by $\Bbb R$.

Comment: That's also pretty vague. By an upper bound of a set $S$ imposed by $\mathbb R$, do you mean an element $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $s\leq x$ for all $s\in S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if $\alpha=n+1$, then $\alpha-1$ is not **strictly less** than $n$. We conclude that $\alpha=n$, but then $n+1>\alpha$.

If you agree that $\Bbb N$ is closed under addition, then the fact that $1\in\Bbb N$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ imply that $n+1\in\Bbb N$. If you don't agree on either of these facts, then you should probably present your definition for $\Bbb N$ so we can work with that.

Comment: How do I know $n + 1$ exists @Asaf Karagila?

Comment: $1$ is a natural number; $n$ is a natural number. The natural numbers are closed under addition.

Comment: so is this due to the axiom of closure? Or can it be proved that a set be closed/open?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: You said the natural numbers are closed under addition. How can I prove they are closed?

Comment: This boils down to the final point in my answer. How do you define the natural numbers? Objects in mathematics have a definition from which we prove their properties. I can't tell you how to prove that if you don't tell me what is the definition of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 5):

If $\alpha$ is a *least* upper bound on $\mathbb{N}$, then $\alpha - 1$ cannot be an upper bound for $\mathbb{N}$, since $\alpha - 1 < \alpha$. Hence, there is a natural number $n$ such that $n > \alpha - 1$; if there wasn't, then $\alpha - 1$ would be an upper bound. Hence, $\alpha < n + 1$ and we go from there.

Comment: But doesn't that imply that $\alpha = n$?

Comment: @MathApprentice No, why? There's no assumption that $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Does that imply $\alpha - 1 < n < \alpha$? After all, since $\alpha$ is not in $N$, then it must bound it. Then that means that $\alpha - 1$ must be contained in $N$. If I am unclear, let me know @T. Bongers.

Comment: @T.Bongers If it's a least upper bound in the set then it surely is in the set...? Unless of course you're embedding the naturals in something else, which begs the question...

Comment: @MathApprentice It implies that $\alpha - 1 < n \leq \alpha$. We have that $\alpha \ge n$ since $\alpha$ is an upper bound.

Comment: @Sharkos There's no condition that a set must contain its least upper bound - from context, we're embedding $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$, so that we can assert that sups exist.

Comment: @T.Bongers Why can't it be that $\alpha - 1 = n$?

Comment: @MathApprentice If there weren't some $n$ with $\alpha - 1 < n$, then $\alpha - 1$ would be a lower bound for $\mathbb{N}$. This contradicts the choice of $\alpha$.

Comment: @T.Bongers That wasn't obvious from context to me at all. Especially since the whole point of the question was to show the sup **doesn't** exist...

Comment: @T.Bongers How do I know that $n + 1$ exists?